# Can't auto-generate an equals method with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, equals

I'm using eclipse to write my Java programs now, but I need to override the `equals` method so it will take the actual data and not the name or id. When I try to auto-generate it the way I know, it says I have no non-static variables. I added some in and it still doesn't work. I don't know enough about Java to do it myself, but I know enough that I would most likely understand what you are talking about. (I'm not done with my code, I just started. The integers `x` and `y` were just to try to make it work.)

```
package mainPackage;
import java.util.*;

public class Main extends Creater {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        thatInput = Inputs.ask();
        Loops.CreateArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The message that you have "no non-static variables" is giving you the right hint. Override the `hashCode` and `equals` methods only makes sense if there are non-static variables in the class. So if you changed your example to the following, you could implement those methods (or have them auto-generated for you by eclipse):

```
public class Main extends Creater {
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // other code
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // ... your equals code goes here
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // ... your hashCode, er, code goes here
    }

    // ... other code that does wonderful things with x and y
}
```

Note how I've moved your `x` and `y` variables to be at the class level rather than at the method level where you had them. Please also note that someone who or something that *creates* is a *creator*, not a *creater*, that I wouldn't recommend naming your package `mainPackage`, and that I wouldn't go importing `java.util.*` in every class just for the sake of it (if you're using eclipse, just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to organise your imports).

Please also see [which issues to consider when overriding these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).

Comment: Could the down-voter please explain what they consider wrong about my answer...?

Comment: when someone has nothing to do, or is upset due to something else in life, or when they wish there left click would have so much power, they simply start down voting on SOF, most times these down votes have no sense.

Answer (score -1):

To automatically add `equals` and `hashCode` methods:

1. Menu -> Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals()
2. Select the fields you want make part of hashCode() and equals()
3. Click Ok

The rest will be done by eclipse.

Comment: The OP said he knew how to auto-generate these methods... the problem wasn't how to do it, it was that he didn't have any variables to base these methods on.